# How to Fix Ornament Circuit Board?

Tags: pcb, repair

So I have my wife’s favorite ornament, she’s had it since she was 3. The ornament hasn’t played music in some time. So I decided to try and surprise her this year and try to fix it. The part in question is a circuit board attached to a 27mm toy loudspeaker.

The paths are corroded, and I was wondering instead of fixing the paths perhaps I can create a new more direct path to complete the circuit. I’ve never done anything like this and thought someone out there might better understand what ends need to connect.

I got new batteries, and if I lay something conductive over the paths I can get it to play (Santa Clause is coming to town) some of the time.

Circuit Board

[image: Circuit Board]

When pressed the black piece is suppose to complete the circuit.
[image: Button]

Answer (score 4):

Those finger-patterns are meant to be shorted by the (conducting) piece of black rubber in the switch. If you have some (push to make) switch you can connect it to the top and bottom horizontal parts of the hands.

Comment: yes, glue a push to make switch into the place between the batteries and solder its leads to the PCB traces, then trim off the pillar in the cover to fit.

Answer (score 1):

The trace that leads to the left-most red wire appears to be damaged, you'll probably need to bridge that damage with a fine wire. doing that should allow the device to play its entire song from just a brief press.

the switch contact fingers are also damaged, the best approach here is probably to replace the entire switch with a small push button and trim the case to accomodate this, however if you want to stay genuine you could instead re-build the contact fingers using fine wire glued to he board and soldered to apropriate traces. use silver plated if possible, silver plating appears to be the finish on that circuit-board.

Answer (score 1):

The entire circuit looks pretty corroded. You can fix it by lightly sanding it down, then using flux, add some solder to every trace. This will repair any small cracks and prevent it from corroding more.

The center traces are for a conductive graphite button. Both the traces and the graphite can wear out. By sanding  and adding some solder, you fix half the issue. The other half if replacing the graphite button. You can find a dollar store remote control to take one out of. Or you can just bypass both by wiring a switch in place instead.

The wire going to the piezo buzzer looks very badly soldered. Cleaning that out with some desoldering braid and resoldering the wire would help.

Answer (score 0):

As Jasen says, a momentary switch across the fingers:
And I'd agree with the damaged trace too:
[image]